# What kind of indexes does Firebird use and why?

Tags: indexing, firebird

According to the [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq205/), indexes are directional, which means they don't use the classical B-Trees implementation. What do they use?

What are the advantages? Do other databases use it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes used by Firebird are [B-trees](https://web.archive.org/web/20231015050240/https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_18), and they are bi-directional, but in practice this bi-directionality is not used because the reverse direction is considered unreliable. This has to do with the order of updates and how Firebird writes pages. As a result, a read in the reverse direction could skip index pages if that read happens at the same time an index page split occurs.

See also [Firebird for the Database Expert: Episode 3 - On disk consistency](https://web.archive.org/web/20230922120943/https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_20):

> If, on the other hand, you need a double linked chain of pages - index
> pages come to mind, there is no separable relationship. Each page
> depends on the other and neither can be written first. In fact,
> Firebird index pages are double-linked, but the reverse link (high to
> low in a descending index) is handled as unreliable. It's used in
> recombining index pages from which values have been removed, but not
> for backward data scans.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided does not contain enough information to make a conclusion about index structure used by Firebird.

AFAIK, Firebird indexes are b-tree variants.  I do not have a direct documentation link right now to support my word, but you can see some references:

- Tracker entry reporting [Wrong index entries order at non-leaf b-tree pages](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1299?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.ext.subversion%3Asubversion-commits-tabpanel) (Firebird tracker)
- Description of [B-tree page structure](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.FirebirdForTheDatabaseExpertEpisode2PageTypes#BTR) for some ODS version (IBExpert documentation)

There are many other examples on the internet, just google it.

Comment: *"The link you provided does not contain enough information to make a conclusion about index structure used by Firebird."* - If they did, I wouldn't have asked.